# Display column from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 4 tables and there are some duplicate columns, and I want to select columns from each table and display every single column from the 4 tables.

system table

```
+------+-------+----------+-------+
| reg  |   ic  |    plate |  type |
+------+-------+----------+-------+
| 1000 | 22222 | WWW123   | car   |
| 1001 | 11111 | BBB987   | truck |
+------+-------+----------+-------+
```

owner table

```
+------+-------+
| name |  ic   |
+------+-------+
| john |  2222 |
| joe  |  1111 |
+------+-------+
```

car table

```
+--------+-------+------+-------+-------+----------+
| plate  | color | year | make  | model | capacity |
+--------+-------+------+-------+-------+----------+
| WWW123 | blue  | 2015 | Honda | City  |      1.5 |
+--------+-------+------+-------+-------+----------+
```

truck table

```
+--------+-------+------+--------+-------+----------+---------+
| plate  | color | year |  make  | model | capacity | maxload |
+--------+-------+------+--------+-------+----------+---------+
| BBB987 | red   | 2018 | Toyota | Hilux |      2.0 |    3000 |
+--------+-------+------+--------+-------+----------+---------+
```

Let's say I want to display every data in this way:

```
+------+------+-------+--------+-------+------+--------+-------+----------+-------+---------+
| reg  | name |  ic   | plate  | color | year |  make  | model | capacity | type  | maxload |
+------+------+-------+--------+-------+------+--------+-------+----------+-------+---------+
| 1000 | John | 22222 | WWW123 | blue  | 2015 | Honda  | City  |      1.5 | car   |         |
| 1001 | Joe  | 11111 | BBB987 | red   | 2018 | Toyota | Hilux |      2.0 | truck |    3000 |
+------+------+-------+--------+-------+------+--------+-------+----------+-------+---------+
```

Is there any possible way to generate SQL that does this?

Comment: There's no Java or PHP involved here... As for the SQL, how familiar are you with joins and selecting individual columns? Also why do you have a car and truck table if the only difference is the max load? Having one table (or a view that combines both) with an additional column "type" would make the query much easier.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out

Comment: I would combine the truck and car table, and allow max-load to be a null. easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select reg,name,A.ic,A.plate,color,year,make,model,capacity,type,maxload 
from systemtable A
inner join ownertable B on A.ic=B.ic
join
(
select plate, color ,year ,make ,model, capacity,null as maxload from car
union all
select plate, color ,year ,make ,model, capacity,maxload from truck
)C on A.plate=C.plate
```

Comment: It shows that " Column 'type' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: why your ic column value is different in your two table one is 22222 in system table and owner table 2222?? @Michael

Comment: Thx!! , so i tried to add `where plate='%s' or ic= '%s'` behind the sql, and it cause this error  ** Column 'plate' in where clause is ambiguous**

Comment: use A.plate @Michael

Comment: for my update sql i did this :`"UPDATE `car` SET `plate`='%s',`color`='%s',`year`='%s',`make`='%s',`model`='%s',`capacity`=%.2f WHERE regno ="`  , but then I realize there is no regno column in car table, what should i do if i insist to use regno

Comment: can you use the plate no to find the reg no @Michael

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for join statements. Since you want to find the intersection between the tables, we are going to use UNION ALL + an inner join (selecting values matching in multiple tables).

```
SELECT name, ic, req, plate, year, color, make, model, capacity, maxload 
FROM ((SELECT * FROM car c WHERE c.plate=plate) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM truck AS t WHERE t.plate=plate))
INNER JOIN owner AS o ON o.ic=ic
```

Try to execute it. You might need to specify every field from car and truck instead of using the asterix (*)

/AF

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers. But here you go.

Table Structure & Data

```
 CREATE TABLE systemtbl
  (
     reg   INT,
     ic    INT,
     plate VARCHAR(255),
     type  VARCHAR(255)
  );

CREATE TABLE ownertbl
  (
     name VARCHAR(255),
     ic   INT
  );

CREATE TABLE cartbl
  (
     plate    VARCHAR(255),
     color    VARCHAR(255),
     year     INT,
     make     VARCHAR(255),
     model    VARCHAR(255),
     capacity DECIMAL(2, 1)
  );

CREATE TABLE trucktbl
  (
     plate    VARCHAR(255),
     color    VARCHAR(255),
     year     INT,
     make     VARCHAR(255),
     model    VARCHAR(255),
     capacity DECIMAL(2, 1),
     maxload  INT
  );

INSERT INTO systemtbl
VALUES      (1000, 22222,'WWW123', 'car'),
            (1001, 11111, 'BBB987', 'truck');

INSERT INTO ownertbl
VALUES      ('john', 22222),
            ('joe', 11111);

INSERT INTO cartbl
VALUES      ('WWW123', 'blue', 2015, 'Honda', 'City', 1.5);

INSERT INTO trucktbl
VALUES      ('BBB987', 'red', 2018, 'Toyota', 'Hilux', 2.0, 3000 );
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT systemtbl.reg,
       ownertbl.name,
       systemtbl.ic,
       systemtbl.plate,
       systemtbl.type,
       tmp.color,
       tmp.year,
       tmp.make,
       tmp.model,
       tmp.capacity,
       tmp.maxload
FROM   (SELECT plate, color, year, make, model, capacity, NULL AS maxload
        FROM   cartbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT plate, color, year, make, model, capacity, maxload
        FROM   trucktbl) tmp
       INNER JOIN systemtbl USING (plate)
       INNER JOIN ownertbl USING (ic)
```

Output

```
+-------+-------+--------+---------+--------+--------+-------+---------+--------+-----------+---------+
| reg   | name  |  ic    | plate   | type   | color  | year  |  make   | model  | capacity  | maxload |
+-------+-------+--------+---------+--------+--------+-------+---------+--------+-----------+---------+
| 1000  | john  | 22222  | WWW123  | car    | blue   | 2015  | Honda   | City   |      1.5  | (null)  |
| 1001  | joe   | 11111  | BBB987  | truck  | red    | 2018  | Toyota  | Hilux  |        2  | 3000    |
+-------+-------+--------+---------+--------+--------+-------+---------+--------+-----------+---------+
```

Online Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52596e/3/0

Comment: @Michael, Just an alias for this query: `'SELECT plate, color, year, make, model, capacity, NULL AS maxload FROM cartbl UNION ALL SELECT plate, color, year, make, model, capacity, maxload FROM trucktbl'`. You can replace it with any name you want. (t1, tmp, abc, etc). If it's making query harder to understand, I'll replace it with `'tmp'`.